# Complete combustion in gas

Tags: mass-energy, combustion

1. Does matter simply releases energy in wood burning fire or does some matter actually convert into energy?
2. Blue flame considered as complete combustion but in ceramic plates gas heaters for room warming, we see/prefer red colour plates?

Comment: Your first question has been answered here before, see [Mass converted to energy in a common fire?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/16351/). Your second question is a bit unclear-- but natural gas burners should produce blue flames according to a number of companies https://www.duke-energy.com/pdfs/100483-natural-gas-safety.pdf https://www.oklahomanaturalgas.com/en/Safety/NaturalGasSafety/AboutCarbonMonoxide.aspx http://www.xcelenergy.com/staticfiles/xe/Marketing/Managed%20Documents/wi-mi-res-bus-welcome-info-sheet.pdf

Comment: In ceramic plate heaters, the (red) light comes from the greatly heated plate's black body radiation, not from the burning/burned gas itself.